# Is there a way to disable default cursor placement when using VueJs?

Tags: vue.js

I am creating a time input text field in which you override zeros with the time that you fill in. When removing your filled in numbers the numbers get replaced with zeros.

When changing the bound text the cursor gets moved to the end of the text and I set the cursor back to the place that it should be located with the setSelectionRange method.

I am trying to disable the cursor placement to the end of the text so the cursor does not bounce around, however I cannot seem to find a way to disable this behaviour.

Can anybody help me to better understand the behaviour of the cursor and how I might be able to disable the movement of it?

I tried to create a time input field without the zeroes but whenever I fill in a number somewhere else then the last character I get a jumpy cursor.

In my example I add a one to the text field with every key press.
You can see the cursor moving to the end of the field before getting placed by the code.

[Fiddle] https://jsfiddle.net/Banthornes/c6zds1h4/1/

```
this.text = this.text + '1'

if(this.cursorLocation > 0)
{
    this.cursorLocation -= 1
}

this.$refs.input.setSelectionRange(this.cursorLocation, 
     this.cursorLocation)
```

I tested this in the following browsers: 
- Chrome
- Firefox
- Brave
- Edge

Answer (score 0):

When you call `setSelectionRange`, the input has not updated yet.

Put your call to `setSelectionRange` in a `setTimeout`.  You might even get away with a `$nextTick`, but in these cases the `setTimeout` is usually more reliable.

```
setTimeout( ()=>{

if(this.cursorLocation > 0)
{
    this.cursorLocation -= 1
}

this.$refs.input.setSelectionRange(this.cursorLocation, 
     this.cursorLocation)


}, 500 )
```

Comment: This does make it look a lot better. Sadly the cursor still gets moved.I would stop it from moving after the input and just move directly to my location.